# Tailwind CSS width property w-11/12 gives 100% instead of 91.66%

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

According to doc, w-11/12 should give me 91.666%:

https://v1.tailwindcss.com/docs/width

But it fills 100%. It works with all other 12th values but 11, has anyone else encountered this bug? Is there a workaround?

w-full and w-11/12 give me the same values.

[image: correct with all values except 11-12]

I tried all different values and all are correct except w-11/12
I am expecing that the width is 91.666% with 11/12 as stated in the documentation

Edit: Added an example:
In this Example I am displaying an horizontal progress bar for all the ratings that are equal to 3. When there are around 90% of values at 3, it should fill 11/12th of the bar, not full. The calculated values are correct as it can be seen in the inspector screenshots.
Also the classnames and styling has been copied over from flowbite docs:
https://flowbite.com/docs/components/rating/

```
    <div className="flex items-center mt-4">
        <span className="text-sm font-medium ">3 star</span>
        <div className="w-2/4 h-5 mx-4 bg-gray-200 rounded dark:bg-gray-700">
            {(ratings.filter(val => val == 3).length / ratings.length * 100 / 8.33) > 0 && (
            <div
                className={`h-5 bg-yellow-400 rounded w-${(ratings.filter(val => val == 3).length / ratings.length * 100 / 8.33).toFixed(0)}/12`}></div>)}
        </div>
        <span
            className="text-sm font-medium ">{(ratings.filter(val => val == 3).length / ratings.length * 100).toFixed(0)}%</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you create a basic example for us to see or provide a link to where the problem is?

Comment: nice to test on play.tailwind.com

Comment: you probably have to rebuild your styles

Answer (score 0):

Try to first share your code. I guess there must be any parent element that must be affecting you bar. I had tried to reproduce your example but Im not able to see the error mentioned by you.

Below is the code and the tailwind play link.

```
<div class="container mx-auto p-24">
  <h3 class="text-xl font-semibold text-purple-900">Tailwind Width</h3>
  <div class="my-5 h-8 rounded-md bg-slate-400">
    <div class="h-8 w-10/12 rounded-md bg-yellow-400"></div>
  </div>
  <p class="-my-2">This is 10/12</p>

  <div class="my-5 h-8 rounded-md bg-slate-400">
    <div class="h-8 w-11/12 rounded-md bg-yellow-400"></div>
  </div>
  <p class="-my-2">This is 11/12</p>
</div>
```

[tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/DlSV4UoWEL)

Comment: I will try to make a reproduceable example. In my case the value is calculated, but not sure that makes a difference. In the console it does correctly show w/11/12